# What options are there for visualising DNA sequences?

Tags: genome, visualization, dna

I typically see several ways of visualising DNA sequences and I would like to know when (best) to use them?

For example, I sometimes see the letter codes GATC, sometimes I see colours, sometimes I see a representation of the double-helix. I think I saw a circular representation.

Additionally, what other options exist for visualising DNA and when should they be used? E.g. for papers, analysis in software, etc.

What do people tend to use when presenting DNA sequences?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hi @ScottMcKenzie. Welcome! Hope you stick around. There are loads of ways to visual sequences and loads of different sequence formats, e.g. alignments, assemblies (NGS stuff) with annotation, nucleotide/allele frequency plots (big letter stuff) ... there are genome and vector (non-mathematical) representations. Could you kindly narrow the question to your specific aim/area please? Maybe tell us your project, type of DNA you want to represent? Otherwise this question will become a thesis of answers.

Comment: Yes, the best way will depend entirely on what you are trying to present. Why are these sequences relevant? What are you trying to say about them?

Answer (score 2):

DNA sequences have a massive range in length, so the approach of visualisation is dependent on the purpose of that visualisation.

I have been experimenting with visualising the repetitive structure of DNA in a way that represents repeats at both short range (tens of bases) and long range (millions of bases, or longer). You can see my attempts at that [here](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/375/finding-the-location-and-unit-length-of-repetitive-sequences-within-a-long-read). An associated presentation about DNA visualisation (with emphasis on repetitive sequences) can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u-v57M7Ldtk).

Comment: This is brilliant, thanks. PS I'm in Auckland! Small world... :)

Comment: If one of the answers here solved your issue, @ScottMcKenzie, please take a moment and [accept it](//bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the checkmark on the left. That is the best way to express your thanks on the Stack Exchange sites.